# how to map a bag/list/set in a class from a table which is got an indirect link to a table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I know the title might sound a bit weird but I've attached a screen of the database design. I have two master tables with a many-to-many relationship in between. But we're using the primary key from the many-to-many table to refer another table called ResourceAllcoation table with the foreign key (ProjectResourceID)

Now what would be the best way to get a bag of ResourceAllocation in the Resource entity? Is there a direct way to do this in nhibernate?

Currently my nhibernate mapping has a one-to-many bag to the ProjectResource table which is then referring the ResourceAllocation table which I feel might not be the best approach.

Please forgive my ignorance. Any thoughts is appreciated. 
[image]

@kalki, when I implemented your mapping, I figured that the sql query getting generated is

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM PROJECTRESOURCE P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RESOURCEALLOCATION  R 
ON P.PROJECTRESOURCEID=R.ID WHERE P.RESOURCEID=1
```

but that doesn't work since ProjectResource doesn't have a PROJECTRESOURCEID column

If the query generated was

```
SELECT * 
FROM PROJECTRESOURCE P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RESOURCEALLOCATION R 
ON P.ID = R.PROJECTRESOURCEID
WHERE P.RESOURCEID=1
```

it would work.

Comment: Since the ProjectResource can have one or many allocations
You could have a ProjectId foreign key within ResourceAllocation then you would be able map it to Project and Vice-Versa

Comment: Thanks. I could have done that but I was wondering if there was an option to do it without that extra reference of the project/resource sitting in the ResourceAllocation table.

Comment: not sure what i was thinking yesterday ! super-brain freeze ! the many-to-many is only possible with a foreign key being present in the join table... with ProjectResource having one or more ResourceAllocation the only way i can foresee the Resource / Project to have a collection of ResourceAllocations if to have foreinkey reference

Comment: Thanks I'll probably redesign the ResourceAllocation table and add in references of the project and resource tables to make a one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

You can map this using a Many-to-Many in NHibernate and an IdBag

Comment: Could you please elaborate this with a nhibernate mapping. I understand the many-to-many part that would like the Project and Resource table but how would I get a collection of ResourceAllocation based on a Resource?